# React Native Bluetooth - control app with bluetooth

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I am working on an app in react native, and I have to connect it with a device through bluetooth. From the device I can control my application, has anyone worked with something similar?

There is very little information on the internet about it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [React Native BLE Manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager). This library is designed for Bluetooth-low-energy devices' integration with React Native.